# APN settings vanish after some time of LTE data usage and only return on restarting phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 4g, oneplus-3

I am using OnePlus 3 and Reliance Jio sim. Android version 6.0.1.

I am able to use 4g data via the sim. Major access point name settings that I get by default from the network:

```
APN: jionet
mcc: 405
mnc: 864
```

It works perfectly for upto 20-30 minutes. After which, my phone can not connect to the 4g network anymore. On further inspection, I go to the APN settings page and get the following message,

> Access Point Name settings are not available for this user.

When I try to manually add these settings and click on the save button, the APN settings dont actually get saved and I still get

> Access Point Name settings are not available for this user.

I need to restart the phone to connect to 4G again, and after 20-30 minutes, the cycle repeats.